# Uncaught TypeError: this.template is not a function Backbonejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am working in Rails with BackboneJS in handlebar templates.

I am getting a weird error here..
this is my header view

```
class App.Views.Header extends Backbone.View

  className: "navbar-inner"
  template: HandlebarsTemplates['app/templates/header']

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template())
    @
```

main application file is this

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./routers

window.App =
  Routers: {}
  Views: {}
  Collections: {}
  Models: {}
  initialize: ->
    new App.Routers.MainRouter()
    Backbone.history.start()
```

and my main router file is this

```
class App.Routers.MainRouter extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    "": "index"

  initialize: ->
    @headerView = new App.Views.Header()

  index: ->
    $("#header").html(@headerView.render().el)
```

when I hit `localhost:3000`.. I got this error upfront. 
`Uncaught TypeError: this.template is not a function`..

Am totally stuck in that any help will be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template: HandlebarsTemplates['header']`

Template path should be only the template itself.

May that is version due to version or assets precompiled

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Handlebars template in `HandlebarsTemplates['app/templates/header']` either does not exist, has not been compiled, or there may have been an error while compiling it.  That's the error you'd get if that value was null or undefined.

You might want to try setting a breakpoint in your browser's javascript debugger in the call to `render`, then use the debugger to check the value of `this.template` and see what's going on.

Comment: `template: HandlebarsTemplates['header']` this worked